# Mapping `ALT + m` to `Esc` in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in Vim, to exit insert mode. I've tried with:

```
map <A-m> <Esc>
```

but it is not working as expected (i.e. it exits insert mode, but the next key pressed is ignored). That's because, apart from exiting insert mode, `m` gets "pressed" or executed as well (i.e. if i remap <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead, then apart from exiting insert mode, it will jump to the next line).

Is there any way to map <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in insert mode without having other side-effects? (avoiding to execute `m` after exiting insert mode)

Using Fedora 21 (GNU/Linux distribution), with GNOME Terminal 3.14.3 and VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40086/exiting-block-insert-mode-with-ctrl-c).  The keyboard combination CTRL + C seems to be special in some way in Vim.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the result would be the same when using `<ESC>` instead.

Comment: It works for me under windows, but I can reproduce the behavior you describe under debian.

Comment: Under linux, alt-m ends up being escape-m when it comes to the OS. You don't need to map <A-m> to anything to get the effect you describe ;) Alt-m is already <escape> followed by <m>.

Comment: `:h :map-alt-keys` could help

Comment: Try this one http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1129

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: deleted my comments to keep this comment section a little bit cleaner. You may want to do the same. This ended up being a kind of long conversation. ;-)

Comment: Done. Though as for me, the conversation was nice ;) People don't (well, at least I don't) read comments if there's only one answer and it is accepted.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: I guess you're right... :-) Thanks again; your trick helped me a lot, my `vimrc` file looks very different (and nicer) now. ;-) Have a nice day!

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: BTW, you see something wrong with my question? I got two downvotes, but no comments on that! xD

Comment: You're welcome ) No, I see nothing wrong with your question. People are strange. I always comment when I downvote something or more often it is already explained in the comments.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: The Doors | People Are Strange: https://youtu.be/Sq9oR9x171w

Comment: yep, something like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inoremap <Esc>m <Esc>
```